# Handler.postDelayed with delayMillis taken from XML file

Tags: android, xml

Wanting to transfer the numeric constants of my application to a file under `res/value/integers.xml`.

I encounter a confusing problem. It concerns the function `Handler.postDelayed`:
the code in `Activity_A`:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
            Intent i_activity_b = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
            Activity_A.this.startActivity(i_activity_b);
            Activity_A.this.finish();
            getApplicationContext().stopService(some_service);;
        }
}, Data.GAME_THREAD_DELAY);
```

This piece of code is supposed to run `Activite_A`, as well as some_service for some time (`GAME_THREAD_DELAY`).

Stop, stop `some_service` and start `Activity_B`.

#### Results

As long as the parameter `GAME_THREAD_DELAY` is taken from a class (`Data.GAME_THREAD_DELAY`) everything is ok. If I take it from an `xml` file (`@ integer / GAME_THREAD_DELAY`), it does not work (`Activity_B` does not start) !!

Could someone help me?

Here is more details :
MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Intent musicIntent = new Intent(this, Music.class);
    musicIntent.putExtra("musicToPlay", Data.SPLASH_MUSIC);
    startService(musicIntent);

    Data.display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
Data.context = getApplicationContext();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView title_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    Animation title_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    title_img.startAnimation(title_animation);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainMenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainMenu);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            getApplicationContext().stopService(musicIntent);;
        }
    }, Data.GAME_THREAD_DELAY);
}}
```

MenuActivity :

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Intent musicIntent = new Intent(this, Music.class);
    musicIntent.putExtra("musicToPlay", Data.Menu_MUSIC);
    startService(musicIntent);

    Data.context = getApplicationContext();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
}}
```

service :

```
public class Music extends Service {
public static boolean isRunning = false;
MediaPlayer player;

public SolarisMusic() {
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int SoundFile, int startId) {
    private static final String TAG = "Music";
    super.onStartCommand(intent, SoundFile, startId);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"null");
    } else {
        int from = extras.getInt("musicToPlay");
        if(from == Data.SPLASH_MUSIC){
            player = MediaPlayer.create(Data.context, Data.SPLASH_MUSIC);
            player.setLooping(Data.LOOP_BACKGROUND_MUSIC);
            player.setVolume(Data.R_VOLUME, Data.L_VOLUME);
            player.start();
        }
        else{
            player = MediaPlayer.create(Data.context, Data.Menu_MUSIC);
            player.setLooping(Data.LOOP_BACKGROUND_MUSIC);
            player.setVolume(Data.R_VOLUME, Data.L_VOLUME);
            player.start();
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public void onStop() {
    isRunning = false;
}
public void onPause() { }
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    player.stop();
}}
```

Comment: Maybe show us the problematic code instead of the working one?

Comment: xml file : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="GAME_THREAD_DELAY">22000</integer>
</resources>`.From the code `R.integer.GAME_THREAD_DELAY`

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment below your question, you're trying to pass the ID of the integer resource as the delay (instead of the value of that resource).

The correct code should look something like this (assuming the name of your integer resource is `GAME_THREAD_DELAY`):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent mainMenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainMenu);
        stopService(musicIntent);
        finish();
    }
}, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.GAME_THREAD_DELAY));
```

Comment: quite simply. Thank's a lot